# Script for changing resolution!

Tags: scripts

I need help writing a script/program that changes my resolution. When I click on that program I want it to change the resolution. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, but I gave it a try and wrote one on my own, but with no success.

So, please help me out! I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

I followed this instruction:
[How can I create an executable in Linux (beginner)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329315/how-can-i-create-an-executable-in-linux-beginner)

I found that this command line worked:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1  --mode 1366x768
```

Now I need help turning it into a script! :)

Ok, so now I created a new textdocument with the name "res" and wrote:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin
chmod +x res.desktop
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1366x768
```

In the terminal I created a .desktop file and wrote:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=<Resolution>
Exec=<~/Desktop/res>
```

The problem now is that there is no file on my desktop except the text document.. Sorry for being quiet the noob on this :)

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: Please post what you've tried till now and change your title to "Script for changing resolution" or something like that, because it is more relevant to the question. Welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: [Resolution documantation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) from [wiki.ubuntu.com](http://wiki.ubuntu.com)

Comment: Two questions:  In your script, is the first line `#!/user/bin` or `#!/bin/bash` - secondly, did you mark the file executable `chmod +x foo.file`

Comment: The first line is #!/usr/bin - and no on the secondth.

Comment: Your above command will work fine in a script with the two lines (the environment declaration @CharlesGreen mentioned + the `xrandr` command). Use `chmod` (above) and you have got your script.

Comment: @jmbjt the `chmod +x foo` tells the filesystem that `foo` is an executable file (a script, for example)

Comment: A file that begins with **.** is hidden so your **.desktop** file becomes hidden. Name it like **res.desktop**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file (res.sh) and past it into

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1024x768
```

and, in your terminal, type :

```
sudo chmod +x res.sh
```

and a create a new .desktop file into : /usr/local/share/applications/

```
gksudo gedit /usr/local/share/applications/res.desktop
```

and past it :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Resolution
Icon=/path/to/icon/res.svg
Exec=/path/to/file/res.sh
```

now you can change resolution by luncher

Comment: ... No need to set `Terminal=true` here :)

Comment: you're right, sorry for mistake  !

Comment: Maybe you also want to hint that there needs to be consistency in the locations of the .desktop file (globally) and the location of the script. (maybe store the `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications)

Comment: personally, I prefere past-it into /usr/local, like that all user have it

Comment: It seems to be working now! Thanks alot everyone!

Comment: To put the .desktop file in `/usr/local/share/applications/` is perfectly allright, but then also put the script in `/usr/local/bin` (globally/globally *or* locally/locally)